# C# UserCredential issue on refreshing token in Parallel context

Tags: linq, oauth-2.0, parallel-processing, credentials, google-api-dotnet-client

The web application is written with C# framework net45.
The credentials are retrieved by this code:

```
private Task<UserCredential> GetCredentialByJSONAsync(FileInfo clientSecrets)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecrets.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        var secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;
        var credentialsDS = new FileDataStore(_credentials, true);
        return GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            secrets,
            _scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            credentialsDS);
    }
}
```

In a LINQ parallel context I get recursively the list of files to recreate the structure of the directory but sometimes happens that I receive an error:

> The process cannot access the file
> 'Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user'
> because it is being used by another process.

The error stacktrace is this:

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
> access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
> bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
> msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
> access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
> msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding
> encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost) at
> System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents,
> Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost) at
> Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore.StoreAsync[T](String key, T
> value) at
> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.d__34.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.d__31.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.d__22.MoveNext() ---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.d__12.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.ResultWithUnwrappedExceptions[T](Task`1 task) at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from
> previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.d__10.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.d__21.MoveNext() ---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.d__17.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.d__71.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.d__69.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.d__34.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() at Google.Apis.Requests.PageStreamer`4.d__5.MoveNext() at
> Imerys.Utilities.GoogleServices.Services.GoogleDriveService.GetFileList(FilesListOptionalParams
> optional)

Do I need to manage the credentials file or does a solution already exist?

Comment: GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is for installed application not web applications.  To answer your question fileDatastore will handle storage of the user credentials when they login (refreshtoken, accesstoken).

Comment: For web app example see [web-applications-asp.net-mvc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc)

Comment: ah sorry, you are right.. but it is not a mvc web app but it is a web handler that doesnt use a controller. The only solution that I found was by using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker. Is it correct?

Comment: So the best way is to implement a custom FileDatastore?

Comment: GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker will not work for a web application it will open the web browser window on the machine which it is running on in this case your web server.  You need to open it up on the client machine.  for that you need to use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow

Comment: If you want to create your own implementation of IDataStore you may want to read about first how filedatastore works https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/.    Then have a look at this Gist its got a bunch of Custom implementations of IDatastore https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/a11851d51f13addd70264d01be1928bf   As not that many people bother with their own implementation i have never gotten around to writing a tutorial on it.   If you have any issues popup a new question i will see if i can help